# How to evaluate this definite integral - $ \int_{0}^{\infty} x \dfrac{p(a+cx)(b+ck) + ab-c}{(1+ak+bx+ckx)^{p+2}} \mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate this integral, with no luck so far:

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} x \dfrac{p(a+cx)(b+ck) + ab-c}{(1+ak+bx+ckx)^{p+2}} \mathrm{d}x$$

Here, $a, b, c, k, p > 0$ are constants.

I'm at a loss on how to proceed. Can anyone give me any hints or point to references that can help evaluate this integral as a closed form expression?

Comment: This one looks ugly.  First of all, please edit your query re what is the **background** of the problem?  
If the problem is from a contest, which contest?  
If (instead) the problem is from a book &/or class, 
what theorems or previously (solved) problems has your 
book or class focused on that you think might be pertinent here? ...see next comment.

Comment: Re previous comment, if background from book or class, regard the background as providing a set of **tools,** and ask yourself what is the teacher/book's *intended* solution.  That is, how should these tools be used?  Normally, I would ask that you try to use the tools, but this problem is so ugly I'm not sure.  Perhaps, you might spend 30 minutes trying to use the tools, and then **show your work.**  ...see next comment.

Comment: If this was an **indefinite integral**, my instinct would run towards some combination of partial fractions and integration by parts.  As such an ugly **definite** integral, where $p$ might not be an integer, I really don't know.  I suspect that someone on mathSE will be able to help, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}x\,{p\pars{a + cx}\pars{b + ck} + ab - c \over \pars{1 + ak + bx + ckx}^{\, p + 2}}\,\dd x}:\
{\Large ?}.\quad a,b,c,k,p > 0\ \mbox{are}}$ *constants*.

---

After some rescaling you are entitled to evaluate the following integral:
$\ds{\left.I_{\alpha} \equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\alpha - 1} \over \pars{1 + x }^{\, p + 2}}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ 0\ <\ \Re\pars{\alpha}\ <\ p\ +\ 2}}$.

In particular, your initial evaluation requires $\ds{I_{2}\ \mbox{and}\ I_{3}}$. $\ds{I_{\alpha}}$ will be convenient evaluated by means of the [Ramanujan's Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem).

---

Note that 
\begin{align}
{1 \over \pars{1 + x}^{\, p + 2}} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{-p - 2 \choose k}x^{k} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{{k + p + 1 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}}x^{k}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
\color{red}{\Gamma\pars{k + p + 2} \over \Gamma\pars{p + 2}}\,{\pars{-x}^{k} \over k!}
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
I_{\alpha} & \equiv
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\alpha - 1} \over
\pars{1 + x }^{\, p + 2}}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ 0\ <\ \Re\pars{\alpha}\ <\ p\ +\ 2}} =
\bbx{\Gamma\pars{\alpha}\,
{\Gamma\pars{-\alpha + p + 2} \over \Gamma\pars{p + 2}}} \\ &
\end{align}
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lclcl}
\ds{I_{2}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{{\Gamma\pars{p} \over \Gamma\pars{p + 2}}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{1 \over \pars{p + 1}p}
\\[2mm]
\ds{I_{3}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{2\,{\Gamma\pars{p - 1} \over \Gamma\pars{p + 2}}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{2 \over \pars{p + 1}p\pars{p - 1}}
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: Nice find! Where did you find this, DLMF or something?

Comment: @K.defaoite I already gave the Wikipedia link. I am not sure of DLMF. Another one is in [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujansMasterTheorem.html). If you look at the internet you'll find a lot of articles. Some of them even include generalizations of the RMT. Thanks.